# latest node(v8.3.0) seems slower

Tags: node.js

I have figured out that the latest released node(v8.3.0) runs much slower than an older version(v6.10.1) by running this simple test code (test.js):

```
var c = 10000*10000;
var t = 0;               
for (var i = 0; i < c; ++i) {
    t += i;    
}                        
console.log(t);
```

Both versions of node projects were configured and built by these commands:

```
ns$ ./configure --debug --gdb; make
```

The test code above was executed for several times by both of the node binaries(release version) built above in this way:

```
ns$ time node test.js
```

For each time, the results looked like:

For v6.10.1:

```
real    0m0.198s
user    0m0.188s
sys 0m0.004s
```

For v8.3.0:

```
real    0m0.488s
user    0m0.456s
sys 0m0.020s
```

I have learned that node v8.3.0 was integrated with the newer version of v8 engine which is said has higher performance, so I supposed that the new version of node should at least run as fast as the old one. But the test results(almost three times slower) told me I was totally wrong! Does anyone know why?

Comment: The performance of Node.js using the new JIT compiler is [_changing_](https://medium.com/the-node-js-collection/get-ready-a-new-v8-is-coming-node-js-performance-is-changing-46a63d6da4de). Lots of things will be faster, but not everything. It's not a generic "everything will be faster" change.

Comment: You might want to report this as a performance regression bug to node or v8. It appears to be off-topic on SO.

Comment: I've found that (at least in the REPL), running a slow script repeatedly tends to make it run faster in consecutive attempts. Perhaps this benchmark isn't fair since it only runs the code a single time for each one. Perhaps after the "warm-up" phase, the difference might be negligible or even in favor of v8.3.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from the new JIT compiler not being a generic "everything will run faster" improvement, there's also a flaw in your testing methodology: you're timing externally, which also counts runtime setup and other one-time costs that aren't a good measure of any speed improvement of the interpreter itself.

I ran the following benchmarking suite (using [`benchr`](https://github.com/robertklep/node-benchr), a benchmark runner that I wrote):

```
suite('loops', () => {

  benchmark('var', () => {
    var c = 10000*10000;
    var t = 0;               
    for (var i = 0; i < c; ++i) {
        t += i;    
    }                        
  });

  benchmark('let', () => {
    let c = 10000*10000;
    let t = 0;               
    for (let i = 0; i < c; ++i) {
        t += i;    
    }                        
  });

});
```

I'm benchmarking both `var` and `let` to show one of the speed *improvements* of Node.js v8. I ran the benchmark using Node.js v6.11.2 and v8.3.0.

The results:

```
# v6
    ✔  var  11.13  ops/sec  ±0.92%  (32 runs)  fastest
    ✔  let   3.72  ops/sec  ±0.87%  (14 runs)  -66.56%

# v8
    ✔  var  11.08  ops/sec  ±1.11%  (32 runs)
    ✔  let  11.11  ops/sec  ±1.26%  (32 runs)
```

Some simple conclusions:

- your test shows that the startup time of the interpreter (from calling the `node` executable to the time it starts running the code) for v8 is a bit higher than for v6
- `let` in v6 is substantially slower than `var`
- there's no real difference between v6 and v8 when running the code using `var` (the timing differences are within the error margins)

As for the last point: I doubt that a main objective of the new JIT compiler was to improve event-loop-blocking code like this.

**EDIT**: I thought it'd be useful to also add the results for v8.2.1:

```
✔  var  11.09  ops/sec  ±1.11%  (32 runs)  fastest
✔  let   0.86  ops/sec  ±0.77%  (7 runs)   -92.21% #
```